# matlab to R: function calling and @

Tags: r, matlab, function, porting

I use `R` but I am translating code from matlab to `R`. I have reached a section which I cannot grok.

My research shows that the `@` allows you to call a function by another name with fixed variables e.g.

```
g = @(b) f(a1, b, c1)
```

allows me to call `f` only specifying `b` by doing `g(b)`

In the code I am working with there is a function

```
function dN = WW(N,h,A,P,aA,aP,bA,bP)
```

at some point in the code it appears `WW`  is called,  but is called with

```
f = @(t,N) WW(N,h,A,P,aA,aP,bA,bP)
```

Why I am so confused is that `t,N` are mentioned nowhere else in the code....but `h,A,P,aA,aP,bA,bP` are all defined prior.

does anyone recognise this structure and what might be going on?

Comment: These are "anonymous functions". The variables in the `@(t,N)` part are function arguments that are in scope only within the anonymous function's body. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in your assessment of `@`.  `@(t)` is what is known as an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).  `@(t)` will thus return a **handle** to a function that takes in one variable `t`.  Basically, it's a function that takes in one parameter, `t`.  The rest of the parameters are defined previously in your workspace.

As an example, your statement of `g = @(b) f(a1, b, c1)` allows you to encapsulate this function call into another function called `g`, and `a1` and `c1` are previously defined in your workspace.  This function will thus rely on one variable that goes into the function, which is `b`.  As such, these parameters will remain static when you call the function `g`, and you can change `b` on the fly.  In other words, every time you call `g`, `a1` and `c1` will **always** stay the same while `b` will change depending on what you put into `g` (check out [Lexical Scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope)).  Obviously, should `a1` and `c1` change in your workspace, this behaviour will be reflected when you call `g` the next time as well.

Now, with the other function call. `t` is never used, but `N` is!  As such, `N` will dynamically change when you vary it, but `t` will have no effect on that function handle of `f`.   No matter how you vary `t`, the output of `f` will be the same, provided that you don't change `N`!

In any case, your assessment is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1):

> at some point in the code it appears
>
> ```
> function dN = WW(N,h,A,P,aA,aP,bA,bP)
> ```
>
> is called, but is called with
>
> ```
> f = @(t,N) WW(N,h,A,P,aA,aP,bA,bP)
> ```
>
> Why I am so confused is that `t,N` are mentioned nowhere else in the
>   code....but `h,A,P,aA,aP,bA,bP` are all defined prior.

That's completely ok. What happens here is that if you do

```
f(value_for_t, value_for_N)
```

it calls

```
WW(value_for_N,h,A,P,aA,aP,bA,bP)
```

(oops? `t` isn't used...)

so everything which contains `t` or `N` is replaced or gone.

Comment: DOH.  I didn't see the `N` there.  I corrected my post.  Thanks for the insight :)